# Adding a value to the user input

Tags: django

I am trying to create a management system with django framework. I am asking if there a way when one tries to input a withdraw, the system stores that withdraw+200 in the database. For example if one input 10000, it stores in the database(models) 10200, thanx

Comment: In your view get the value and add 200 to it and then save. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. When you take the input add 200 to the value, then save it into your model.

```
def store_add_200(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        data += 200
        data_model = DataModel(value=data)
        data_model.save()
```